# Not fill the grid

Tags: vb.net, mdiparent

Good day,

I have a problem in an MDI form, have the main form, and have 2 buttons, these buttons lead to children forms, one of the forms allows you to select a category from a database, and fills the grid within the, everything works until I I embed the form within the MDI using the button that event is as follows:

```
Private Sub ButtonCatego_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles ButtonCatego.ItemClick
    Dim addCategory As New AddCategory
    addCategory.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
    addCategory.Show()
End Sub
```

When i use the normal event works:

```
Private Sub ButtonCatego_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles ButtonCatego.ItemClick
    AddCategory.Show()
End Sub
```

Help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `addCategory.MdiParent` to your current form's MDI parent. If `Me` is your main form then it won't have an MDI parent, which is why you're not getting it to work.

Set `addCategory.MdiParent` to `Me` instead and it should resolve your issue:

```
Private Sub ButtonCatego_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles ButtonCatego.ItemClick
  Dim addCategory As New AddCategory()
  addCategory.MdiParent = Me      
  addCategory.Show()

End Sub
```

Comment: You should rather add an explanation about what he missed/what he did wrong instead of just saying something similar to "Try this" or "This works".